# Poco Get Logger Channel from SplitterChannel

Tags: c++, logging, poco-libraries

In my application i load the Configuration for the Logger from an XML Configuration File. This works fine. For my Logger i have to Channels configured. One which logs to an File and another on which logs to the console.

With `logger.getChannel()` i can obtain the `SplitterChannel`. But i need access to the containing Channels. But i did not figure out an way to get the 2 Channels out of the `SplitterChannel`

This is the Code to load the Logging Configuration:

```
if (Poco::File{ configPath }.exists()) {
    try {
        Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration> loggingConfig{ new Poco::Util::XMLConfiguration{configPath.toString()} };
        Poco::Util::LoggingConfigurator logConf;
        logConf.configure(loggingConfig);
        auto logFilePath = loggingConfig->getString("logging.channels.c1.path");

        Poco::File logFile{ Poco::Path{logFilePath}.parent() };
        if (!logFile.path().empty() && !logFile.exists()) {
            logFile.createDirectories();
        }
        Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration> linesyncView{ loggingConfig->createView("LineSync") };
        displayThreadNames = linesyncView->getBool("displayThreadNames", false);
    } catch (const Poco::Exception&) {
        poco_error(logger, "Could not load Config File");
    }
}
```

And this is the Logging Configuration:

```
<config>
<logging>
    <channels>
        <c1>
            <class>FileChannel</class>
            <path>C:\Log\log.log</path>
            <rotation>100 M</rotation>
            <archive>timestamp</archive>
            <compress>true</compress>
            <formatter>
                <class>PatternFormatter</class>
                <pattern>%L%d-%m-%Y;%H:%M:%S;%s(%U [%u] );[%p %I];%t</pattern>
            </formatter>
        </c1>
        <c2>
            <class>ColorConsoleChannel</class>
            <pattern>%s(%U [%u]): [%p %I] %t</pattern>
        </c2>
        <splitter>
            <class>SplitterChannel</class>
            <channels>c1,c2</channels>
        </splitter>
    </channels>
    <loggers>
        <root>
            <channel>splitter</channel>
            <level>information</level>
        </root>
    </loggers>
</logging>
</config>
```

Comment: Actually, it is not possible. SplitterChannel should be modified to expose access to channel's vector. It could be easily done if you compile your own Poco libraries.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need access to the channels.  You should just be able to use the `RootLogger()` to get and use the logger which will output to both channels.  BTW, I would recommend using an `AsyncChannel` before the splitter for performance reasons.