# Is it possible to set channel specific priorities for Poco logger?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

In my application I am setting up a logger from a config file similar to how [Poco Get Logger Channel from SplitterChannel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949341/poco-get-logger-channel-from-splitterchannel) is setting the logger up however I want to modify my configuration so that the logging priority is set on a per channel basis, ie `FileChannel` can log at the `PRIO_INFORMATION` level and the `ColorConsoleChannel` can log at the `PRIO_WARNING` level etc. Is this possible? If so how would I modify setting up the logger to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that you cannot set channel specific priority levels. My solution was to make a `LogManager` class that loads in my logging xml config and has 3 loggers with different priority levels, a file logger set to trace, a console logger set to warning, and a run logger set to trace that uses a `SplitterChannel` to write to both. Then implementing class level methods `[trace(), debug(), information(), etc]` that call their corresponding poco logging method, ex:

```
void LogManager::information(std::string message) {
    poco_information(_fileLogger, message);
    poco_information(_consoleLogger, message);
}

void LogManager::warning(std::string message) {
    poco_warning(_fileLogger, message);
    poco_warning(_consoleLogger, message);
}

void LogManager::runInfo(std::string message) {
    poco_information(_runLogger, message);
}
```